# Raspberry pi 4 shows solid red light

Tags: raspbian, boot

My raspberry pi 4 is showing a solid red light, the green light stops blinking shortly after I power on. Everything was working fine up until last night, I have the raspberry pi power adapter, 64GB memory card and was running the Raspbian image downloaded by the Raspberry pi imager tool.
Last night I changed the Wi fi network it uses, I was interfacing with the pi via an ethernet cable directly from my laptop. I came back later in the evening and nothing was working, I have re-imaged the card, and tried a both SSH and VNC, but nothing is accepting the connection, the only thing that is responding is the ping on the address of that network interface.
I was wondering does anybody have any idea what happened here, and is there any way to fix it?
Could something have happened during shutdown that caused something to get corrupted? The only major change I made was to change the WiFi network, but even now after a full re-image nothing is working. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you connect the Pi4 to a screen via hdmi? Do you get the boot loader screen with no sd card? Have you read the boot sticky? https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=58151#p1485558

Comment: Sadly no, I dont have the specific HDMI cable that it needs.

Comment: Try a different sd card and I would order an hdmi cable https://thepihut.com/collections/raspberry-pi-hdmi-cables/products/hdmi-to-micro-hdmi-cable-2m-gold-plated

Comment: Hmmmm, any idea how this could have happened? It is quite frustrating to just come back and find everything totally broken like this.

Comment: That the red PWR led is on is totally normal.  If it were not, that might indicate a problem. So is irregular flashing of the green LED, subsiding after 10-20s or so.  *"even now after a full re-image nothing is working"* -> It honestly sounds like you are just wasting your time, and probably will again in the future unless you get **a micro HDMI cable**, they are the same price as regular ones ($5-10 USD) and available almost anywhere.  But if you consider your time (and the time of people you are asking for help from) to be worth nothing, then of course save your money ;)

Comment: If ping is working that means the Pi is okay and running.  Please edit your question and give the SSH error message.

Comment: `the ping on the address of that network interface` - how do you know the address?

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your comment "how could this have happened" powering off without shutting down the Pi first can corrupt the SD card  sometimes to the point it's no longer usable.

Comment: Wouldnt formatting the card and re-imaging solve this though ??

Comment: In my experience the sd card can become unusable when this happens, not every time but often enough. Practically all my Pi's now boot from SSDs via USB to SATA adapters which are much more robust,. I've yet to have a failure.

Comment: This is NOT an answer, it''s missing supporting information to qualify as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Isolate the Pi issues by supplying a known good SD with a fresh install Raspbian OS with your wpa_supplicant.conf  adjusted to your network AP settings, and copy that folder to the SD's /boot folder.
As stated, the ping response is software from the Pi responding to the ping request.

If you are using ethernet as you say, then try pluggin it into your router.

So if you get a ping back then more than likely your Pi is alive.
Try putting Pi on your network, not direct to the Laptop.  You might have different IP address because of that.

If you setup the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file:

```
    ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
    update_config=1
    country=GB

    network={
             ssid="IoT-Lab"
             psk="12323233"
             key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    }


    network={
            ssid="Node1"
            wep_key0="6172736869"
            #wep_key0=6172736869
            key_mgmt=NONE
    }
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46276408/how-to-connect-raspberry-to-wep-encrypted-and-dhcp-enabled-ad-hoc-network

Use this as a template, so change according to your wifi setup, and save the file to your /boot folder on the SD... On next boot, your Pi will save these settings and connect via wifi if you have it.

***Please note that some Pi models come with low amounts of RAM memory, and if you max this out, your Pi can become unresponsive.